# ifort -> gfortran: array - Incompatible ranks 2 and 1 in assignment at (1)

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I'm trying to move below Intel Fortran line to gfortran, but I get following error:

```
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(0:0,0:0) :: value = (/ -999D99 /)

Incompatible ranks 2 and 1 in assignment at (1)
```

If I understand it correctly, we are creating a 2-dim array with 1 element. I came with following fix. Is this standard conforming?

```
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(0:0,0:0) :: value = reshape ((/-999D99/), shape(value))
```

Comment: I am surprised Intel accepted this. BTW, why not just `value = -999D99`?

Comment: My background is not fortran. The solution seems working for me but I would like to be 100% sure that it is correct. Vladimirs solution works and it seems cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not allowed to make an assignment (even in initialization) between arrays of different ranks. Therefore the line

```
...DIMENSION(0:0,0:0) :: value = (/ -999D99 /)
```

is illegal.

Reshaping the right hand side to an array of rank 2

```
...DIMENSION(0:0,0:0) :: value = reshape ((/-999D99/), shape(value))
```

is a standard conforming solution, but it is easier to assign a scalar:

```
...DIMENSION(0:0,0:0) :: value = -999D99
```

Of course, this will work only if you have just 1 value. It will be assigned to all elements of the array on the left hand side.